# How to make backticks accept variables as variables?

Tags: bash

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

machine_we_are_looking_for=$1
user_defined_new_machine_location=$2


condition_while_one=true
condition_while_two=true



echo "test 1"

while $condition_while_one
do




    first_awk_variables=`tail -n1 /mydriectory/myonlycsvfile.csv | awk -F, '{print $3, $4, $5, $7, $10 }'`
    first_awk_variables_value_array=($first_awk_variables)          #turns contents of 'first_awk_variables' into an array 'first_awk_variables_value_array'


  value_stat=${first_awk_variables_value_array[3]}

  machine_location=${first_awk_variables_value_array[0]}
  machine_ID=${first_awk_variables_value_array[1]}
  machine_No=${first_awk_variables_value_array[2]}
  machine_title=$machine_ID'-'$machine_No
  echo "$value_stat of $machine_title at $machine_location"

    if [ "$value_stat" == "status" ] && [ "$machine_title" == "$machine_we_are_looking_for" ]
        then


                 #change location of machine
                `mosquitto_pub -t '/$user_defined_new_machine_location/cmd' -m '-changelocation'`

              condition_while_one=false   
        fi



done
```

With this I want to 'publish' to the MQTT stream. The publishing part works great but it takes the variable name `$location` literally, and doesn't substitute `$location` with the initialized value for like `NYC`,`Paris` or `Tokyo`.

**Q:** How can I make it so that the assigned value/string gets substituted to `$location` when the code is executed

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand because you aren't showing your actual code. Write four spaces at the beginning of a line or use the `{}` button on the edit bar, then copy-paste your exact code.

Comment: Use double quotes "$location" instead of singles '$location'

Comment: @Gilles, I've uploaded the code, any help/suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: @don_crissti The backticks are there to execute `mosquito_pub -t..`  as it was run in the terminal. As for the reason is that's the only way I know..

Comment: @3kstc - what are you talking about ? You don't need those, just run the command... Read _gilles_ answer.

Comment: Also, I advise you to get into the habit of using `$(...)` instead of `\`...\``. It'll make your life much easier. [Here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: @3kstc - c'mon... you DON'T need backticks or `$()` for `mosquitto_pub...`. You simply run the command WITHOUT them. You **only** need them on the upper line: `first_awk_variables=\`tail -n1 ...` where you _assign the output of the command_ to a variable. Also, surround your variables with double quotes, as per two of the three answers here. Please do some reading on _command substitution_ and _variable expansion_ .

Answer (score 2):

Strings in single quotes are used as-is. In a single-quoted string, the only special character is the `'` single quote character, which ends the string.

In strings in double quotes, the characters `"\`$`are special:`"`ends the string,`` makes the next character lose its special interpretation, `` ` `` starts a command substitution, and `$` starts a variable substitution, command substitution or arithmetic expansion. Thus, since you want to expand variables, use double quotes instead of single quotes. This is unrelated to the use of a command substitution.

In additition, the command substitution doesn't make sense in context. You're taking the output of the command `mosquitto_pub …`, splitting it at whitespace, interpreting each of the resulting words as a glob pattern and using the result of this expansion as a command and its arguments. I'm not sure what this program is trying to do; if you just want to run the `mosquitto_pub` command, remove the backticks. If you want to assign its output to a variable, you need to write an assignment like

```
some_variable=`mosquitto_pub -t "/$user_defined_new_machine_location/cmd" -m '-changelocation'`
```

On an unrelated note, don't use variable names like `condition_while_one`. This name is meaningless. Use a name that reflects what the variable is used for. For this specific example, you don't need the variable at all — do this instead:

```
while true; do
  …
  if …; then
    mosquitto_pub …
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: There won't be any input from that command, the `mosquitto_pub` sends _out_ a command to the MQTT stream where received by the remote PC and processed to change the `location` of the `machine_we_are_looking_for`

Comment: @3kstc Did you mean “there won't be output from that command”? Then why would you use a command susbtitution on it? Just write the command.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant! I meant "There won't be any OUTput from that command". Alas when I remove the back ticks the variables still get sent out as literals ie `$location` into the MQTT stream where it should _actually be_ `NYC`

Comment: @3kstc As several of us have told you, this has nothing to do with backticks, you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to do:

1. you don't need backticks around your invocation of `mosquitto_pub`
2. your `-t` parameter to `mosquitto_pub` should be surrounded with
   double-quotes (`"`) rather than single-quotes (`"`)

In particular (2) here is the cause of your problem. Single-quotes will not permit the evaluation of `$` variables.

```
    if ...
    then
      #change location of machine
      mosquitto_pub -t "/${user_defined_new_machine_location}/cmd" -m '-changelocation'
       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As roaima said in a comment, you should use double quotes for variables you want expanded (so, `"$location"`), as single quotes protect variables from being expanded.